# Detect cycle in an undirected graph using DFS

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I am trying to detect cycle in an undirected graph. I am using DFS to detect the same. For any node, I will visit through all connected nodes. If the child node is already visited and its not parent of current node, We have a cycle in graph.

I wrote below code :

```
public boolean isCyclicUtil(int current, boolean[] visited, int parent, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adj) {
    visited[current] = true;
    Iterator<Integer> it = adj.get(current).iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        int nextNode = it.next();
        if (!visited[nextNode]) {
            return isCyclicUtil(nextNode, visited, current, adj);
        } else {
            if (nextNode != parent)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean isCycle(int V, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adj) {
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[V];
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
        if (!visited[i] && isCyclicUtil(i, visited, -1, adj)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It is failing for certain test cases. I am not able to figure out what is wrong with the code.
Please help me understand bug in my code.

Comment: *Please share the link of the problem as well. If possible, share any input instance where it is going wrong.* I did test it against few inputs, it did work correctly on them.

Comment: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/detect-cycle-in-an-undirected-graph/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of visiting all adjacent vertices, you stop exploring them after visiting the first adjacent vertex that has not been visited yet because of the return statement:

```
if (!visited[nextNode]) {
    return isCyclicUtil(nextNode, visited, current, adj);
}
```

Your search space from a single `isCyclicUtil` execution essentially becomes a path, and some vertices will not be visited. They will of course be visited in some later iteration within `isCycle` function, but it might be a good exercise to understand why some cycles might not be detected this way.

Fixing is easy - you want to return only if you have actually found a cycle.

Comment: Thanks a lot. changing the code as mentioned below worked:
            `code`  if (!visited[nextNode]) {
    if(isCyclicUtil(nextNode, visited, current, adj))
        return true;
   } else {
    if (nextNode != parent)
     return true;
   }  `code`